# In Reynolds transport theorem, is the integral region simply-connected?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes, transport-phenomena

Reynolds transport theorem for a *material element* (parcels of fluids or solids which no material enters or leaves) reads $^1$
$$
(1):\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{\Omega(t)} \mathbf{f}\,dV\right) = \int_{\Omega(t)} \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial t}\,dV + \int_{\partial \Omega(t)} (\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n})\mathbf{f}\,dA.
$$
This is because
$$(2):\mathbf{v}^{b}\cdot\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n}\\\\$$
where $\mathbf{v}^{b}$ is the velocity of the area element, $\mathbf{n}dA$, and $\mathbf{v}$ is fluid (or solid) velocity.

## Question

Does (1) still hold if the simply-connected region $\Omega(t)$ changes to a multiply connected region over time?

**P.S.**: I am a mechanical engineering student, not a mathematics student, and I don't know anything about differential geometry.
1: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem)

Comment: The theorem holds as long as all the quantities are nice and smooth and integrable enough, and the regions involved are nice and smooth; smooth enough that Leibniz's rule for differentiation of the integral can be applied, and smooth enough for Stokes theorem to be applied. The actual topology of the region (simply vs multiply connected or whatever) doesn't play a role.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Assume a bubble, in which we embed a continuum, flows in water. It splits to two smaller bubbles over time. Am I correct that Eq. 1 is valid up to the time in which split occurs? BTW, I think Stokes theorem is not relevant to Eq. 1, but Leibniz's rule and Green-Gauss theorem are.

Comment: When I said Stokes' theorem, I was using it as an umbrella term (as is common in differential geometry) to mean the "Generalized Stokes theorem", which has as special cases the classical Stokes theorem, Gauss'/Ostrogradsky/Green DIvergence theorem, and also Greens' theorem (which is 2D). Like I said, this theorem makes no assumption about the topology of the regions considered, only their smoothness. Regarding the bubble splitting into two, that's impossible if you assume your region $\Omega$ varies smoothly over time (the image of connected sets under continuous maps is connected).

Comment: So, yes, $\Omega(t)$ varies smoothly up until the time of splitting, so until that point, the equation will hold, because the various smoothness hypotheses of all the theorems are satisfied. If you want to investigate carefully what happens after the split, then you need to be very explicit about the various hypotheses you're imposing (on the smoothness of the maps involved, and how exactly you're deforming the region etc).